# Rotating two 3D images in sync using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to rotate two 3D images simultaneously on mouse click event. Images are rotating but there is slightly angular difference in their rotation. i.e. the images are not getting rotated in sync.

I have used two functions with reference to three.js sample code.
First function is init() it contains initialization details. I have also used TrackBallControls for zooming effect.

```
function init() {
    document.getElementById("image").addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    container = document.getElementById('image');
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 100, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 100000);
    camera.position.z = 700;

    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
    controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
    controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
    controls.panSpeed = 0.8;
    controls.noZoom = false;
    controls.noPan = false;
    controls.staticMoving = false;
    controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;
    controls.keys = [ 65, 83, 68 ]; 

    controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xFFFFFF );
    scene.add( ambient );

    try {
            webglRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            webglRenderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
            webglRenderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";
            container.appendChild( webglRenderer.domElement );
    }catch (e) {}

    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

    var callbackLeft = function ( geometry, materials ) {createScene( geometry, materials, -400, FLOOR, 50, 105 )   };

    var callbackRight = function ( geometry, materials ){createSceneRight( geometry, materials, 400, FLOOR, 50, 105 ) };

    loader.load( "../view3D/Female02_slim.js", callbackLeft );
    loader.load( "../view3D/Female02_slim.js", callbackRight ); 
}
function createScene( geometry, materials, x, y, z, b ) 
{
    zmesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
    zmesh.position.set( x, y, z );
    zmesh.scale.set( 3, 3, 3 );
    THREE.GeometryUtils.center( geometry );
    scene.add( zmesh );
}
function createSceneRight( geometry, materials, x, y, z, b ) 
{
    zmeshRight = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
    zmeshRight.position.set( x, y, z );
    zmeshRight.scale.set( 3, 3, 3 );
    THREE.GeometryUtils.center( geometry );
    scene.add( zmeshRight );
}
function onDocumentMouseMove(event) 
{
    mouseX = ( windowHalfX -  event.clientX);
}
function animate() 
{
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();
    render();
}

var prevMouseX = 0;
function render() 
{
    if(mouseX > -300)
        {
            zmesh.rotation.y -= 0.8;
            zmeshRight.rotation.y -= 0.8;
        }
        else if(mouseX < -300)
        {
            zmesh.rotation.y += 0.8;
            zmeshRight.rotation.y += 0.8;
        }
        else
        {
            zmesh.rotation.y += 0;
            zmeshRight.rotation.y -= 0.8;
        }

    webglRenderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Please advise

Comment: `render` function last `else` block  `zmesh.rotation.y += 0;` and `zmeshRight.rotation.y -= 0.8;`. Different rotation, isn't here a problem?

Comment: Not actually.I tried the change but didn't work.

Comment: A possible workaround. If angular difference is always the same, you can set zmeshRight rotation when object is created `zmeshRight.rotation.set(0, 0.2, 0)`. Adjust rotation.